# changing all fabs animation speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to change/update my fabs speed but this code only updates newly generated fabs speed
How can I do that?

```
IEnumerator Fade()
{
    while (true) { 




        gelencizgi = Instantiate(gelencizgi, new Vector3(1298, 1.2f, 126.1f), Quaternion.identity);
        gelencizgi.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("gelencizgi");
        gelencizgi.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("myspeed", .2f * hizkatsayisi);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f/hizkatsayisi);  
        Destroy(gelencizgi, 2/hizkatsayisi);
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to loop through all your already spawned fabs and update the speed to match. Rather than having the destroy command set into the function, I recommend using that loop through to check destroys instead. Give all your fabs a "created" time marker variable and check against that to perform your animation and destroy adjustments against so that you can check them in batches and adjust as needed.

Comment: hpw can i set speed for pre generated fabs this code curreently changes the newly generated ones

Comment: Another alternative depending on what your prefabs are doing would be to change the destroy command to be based on a collision instead of time based. For example, if your prefabs are bullets traveling outwards then put a invisible sphere around the area that once the bullet collides with the sphere it's destroyed. This lets you adjust the bullet's speed however you want since it being destroyed is not reliant on timing to do so.

Comment: Take your reference to your prefab when you make it and save it in an array or a list. From there, you can loop through this array/list to update the prefabs animation. Just be sure to remove it from the array/list before destroying it.

Comment: As for changing all the animations at once, it appears you can change it all through the Animator object for all animations associated to it. An example of this can be found [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/902029/how-to-get-and-change-animation-speed-of-animator.html).